# CGO: how to free the go slice which is backed by a C Array

Tags: go, cgo

CGO Wiki: https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/cgo#turning-c-arrays-into-go-slices
This explains how to convert the c arrays into go slices (without copying the original data) and it also makes a statement:
"**It is important to keep in mind that the Go garbage collector will not interact with this data, and that if it is freed from the C side of things, the behavior of any Go code using the slice is nondeterministic.**"

But my doubt is, after we are done using this slice, how do we free the memory allocated for the slice? the backing C array can be freed by appropriate calls to the C world, but what about the slice? will it be garbage collected?

Also,

`slice := (*[1 << 28]C.YourType)(unsafe.Pointer(theCArray))[:length:length]`

will this statement **allocate** a pretty big array and then slice? I mean, will it cause a BIG memory allocation? if so, how and when will that BIG memory be freed?
it is also confusing to understand that the slice will be 'backed by the C array'.
if the slice is backed by the C array, then why is a BIG array `[1<<28]` required?

Comment: `*[1 << 28]C.YourType` is just a type, it does not allocate anything

Comment: thanks @JimB.
what about the slice variable? will its memory, which is usually like 12 bytes: 
4 bytes for pointer
4 bytes for length and
4 bytes for capacity,
be Garbage collected?

Comment: The slice variable is like any other variable. If you have: `func f() { var i int; ... }` are you worried about the variable `i` being garbage collected? If so, why?

Comment: @torek indeed, for normal variables this confusion won't be there. but this slice is backed by C memory, which is not touched by the Garbage collector. So, my question is how the life of this slice, which is kind of mixup of C and GO worlds, is handled?

Comment: A slice variable consists solely of a slice *header*. The backing array, if there is one, is independent of the header. Separately, if a Go pointer value *p* points to some Go object *O*, object *O* remains alive. If a Go pointer value points to some C object, the C object is never garbage collected in the first place: only Go objects can be GCed.